# Sequelize 6 override determined column name

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a Sequelize column named item_ListID - this name is for various reasons. However, v6 Sequelize attempts to do queries with item_list_i_d. How can I have it not do that? The data type is TEXT.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to setup the column in the model as such:

```
columnName: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    field: "different_column_name"
}
```

Where `field` is the name of the actual column name, and Sequelize won't attempt to change it.